# How can I add an Information image on Google Map Marker?

Tags: javascript

I have a problem with adding information windows in my app. My target is to add, for each marker, a specific photo.

I have copied the code from Google Maps JavaScript, but I am lost a bit.

Here is the code below.

```js
var neighborhoods = [
  {lat: 52.511, lng: 13.447},
  {lat: 52.549, lng: 13.422},
  {lat: 52.497, lng: 13.396},
  {lat: 52.517, lng: 13.394}
];

var markers = [];
var map;

function initMap() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 12,
    center: {lat: 52.520, lng: 13.410}
  });
}

function drop() {
  clearMarkers();
  for (var i = 0; i < neighborhoods.length; i++) {
    addMarkerWithTimeout(neighborhoods[i], i * 200);
  }
}

function addMarkerWithTimeout(position, timeout) {
  window.setTimeout(function() {
    markers.push(new google.maps.Marker({
      position: position,
      map: map,
      animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP
    }));
  }, timeout);
}

function clearMarkers() {
  for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
    markers[i].setMap(null);
  }
  markers = [];
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Although you have specified what you need, you should also tell us what's your specific problem here. Please also read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask . Best regards.

Answer (score 0):

```
function drawMarker(image,title,latlng)
{   
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({position: latlng,map: map,title:title,icon:image});
    array.push(marker);

    showHideInfoWindow(marker,infowindow, id);
}

function showHideInfoWindow(overlay,infowindow, id)
{
    if(overlay instanceof google.maps.Marker)
    {
        google.maps.event.addListener(overlay, 'click', function() { 
            infowindow.close(); infowindow.open(map,overlay); 
        });


    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for replying.
I want to know, about the code the wrote above, should I paste it 
like this or there are some thing else to modify.
Sorry but I am real beginer at Javascript.
Thanks